# restrict_xpaths parameter not filtering crawled data

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy 1.0.5 and trying to crawl a series of articles to fetch their title and respective URL. I only want to crawl the links inside a `div` element with an ID of `devBody`. With that in mind, I tried to specify such a restriction in a rule but I can't figure out why it's still crawling links outside of that scope:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from stack.items import StackItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["dev.mysql.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="devBody"]',), callback='parse'),)

    def parse(self, response):
        entries = response.xpath('//h4')
        items = []
        //using a counter here feels lame but I really couldn't think of a better 
        //way to avoid getting a list of all URLs and titles wrapped into a single object
        i = 0            
        for entry in entries:
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = entry.xpath('//a/text()').extract()[i]
            item['url'] = entry.xpath('//a/@href').extract()[i]
            yield item
            items.append(item)
            i += 1
```

In trying to understand the behavior, I've used Chrome Dev Tools to query the elements using XPath and everything works as it [should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPjxY.png). However, when I (try to) put the same sequence of steps in my code, things don't go the same way. It's fetching data outside of the `div` which ends up [misplacing](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ed8470aae2325174efde) the URL for a given article. 
It does say it fetched the 57 wanted [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW7gh.png) but then something goes wrong along the way.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to base your `StackSpider` class on the `CrawlSpider` class, its the one that has the `rules` attribute. See the [docs here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider). You will need to rename your parse() method and change the callback as the CrawlSpider has it's own parse() as mentioned in the docs.

Or plan B.

The CrawlSpider doesn't add much to scraping this page. It is pretty simple to use an ordinary spider and loop over the 'h4/a' combo to get the information you want. Try this

```
for row in response.xpath('//div[@id="devBody"]/h4'):
    item['title'] = row.xpath('a/text()').extract()
    # get the full url
    item['url'] = response.urljoin(row.xpath('a/@href').extract_first())
    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I had read that and a couple other threads here on SO but it didn't even cross my mind to check those details. I made the adjustments you mentioned but now it seems to be filtering _out_ the items I _want_ to fetch. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/78e06834119dc9d9f365)'s my current code and [output](http://i.imgur.com/fGEfYdk.png) behavior.

Comment: @w00t I've edited my answer with another suggestion that will get you what you want.